# c# post complex object to php [Xamarin]

Tags: c#, php, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

What I want to achieve is to send to PHP complex object to PHP, currently using [wsd-data](https://github.com/norman784/wsd-data) but only sends the properties values from the root, ie:

```
public class Post : Collection<Post>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public File Image { get; set; }
}

byte[] fileContents = ....;

Post post = new Post();
post.Title = "Post title";
post.Content = "Post content";
post.Image = new File ("FileName.png", "image/png", fileContents);
await post.Save();
```

In this case works perfectly because it handles the File case internally, but if I add a nested dependency like

```
public class Post : Collection<Post>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public File Image { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say that Author is a class that have name, id, etc, but when I post it only sends the Author.toString() value, I tried to add an array like key to post to PHP like:

```
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent ();
form.Add (new StringContent (post.Author.Name), "Author[Name]");
form.Add (new StringContent (post.Author.Id), "Author[Id]");

await httpClient.PostAsync (url, form).ConfigureAwait (false);
```

Then in PHP I want to receive something like this:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['Author']['Name']; // must print the author name
?>
```

But I just got an empty $_POST['Author'] variable, dunno how to achieve with c#, if I need to change internally how to create the form body just let me know, but would like to use form-data because it support file submission.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution (was a flaw on the library) its [here](https://github.com/norman784/wsd-rest/blob/master/RequestContent.cs)

Basically I map recursively the complex dictionary to a much simple one (one level with  values). i.e.

```
// Pseudo class with data
Post {
  Id=0,
  Title="Hello world",
  List<Comment> Comments=[
    Comment { Id=0, Description="This is a comment" }
  ]
}

// Pseudo dictionary result

Dictionary<string, string> data = {
  Id=0,
  Title="Hello World",
  Comments[0][Id]=0,
  Comments[0][Description]="This is a comment"
}

// And then in php get (all keys are converted to lowercase

echo $_POST['id']; // 0
echo $_POST['title']; // Hello World
echo $_POST['comments'][0]['id']; // 0
echo $_POST['comments'][0]['description']; // This is a comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like using serialization would be a better option than trying to process your input as form data. I haven't done much PHP in along time, but I've done plenty of web services. Just serialize it on the Xamarin end, and deserialize it on the PHP end.

Comment: Could be a solution, but I found one, your solution would work but I've already implemented in a service this library, so if sent the data serialised it would break the old app that is running with it or would add much code (in php side) to solve this issue, when there was another easier way to solve it. I appreciate your answer as well. Regards